# LAN Share folder and enclosed folders

Tags: lan

As a no-programmer we are having the following problem. I've shared and set permissions on folders with groups. Everything works as a charm except we can't see the content of the underlying folders (Folder #1 > Folder #1.1 > files).

Does anyone know how we can show all underlying folders as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out myself.

Due to 'protection' subfolders aren't readable by default. You need to chmod (777) all folders with the following command:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 folder.
```

In my case:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/username/folder
```